# Firestore rules to restrict users to their section of the DB

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am wondering how to restrict firebase to only the specific section of the DB that they own.

Here's basically of what I want:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
    match /users/{userid} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userid;
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the above doesn't work?
And how to fix it in order to restrict users to ONLY their data?

Thanks in advance.
Nikita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of this rule:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read: if true;
}
```

It allows read access to all documents in the database to everyone, unconditionally, and it's overriding the other rule that you've written.  Remove this rule if you don't want everyone to be able to read every document in your database.

There is one important thing you need to remember about security rules: **if any rule allows access to a document, another rule cannot undo that**.

Comment: I want users to be able to read&write /users/{theirUserId} and only read /stats/*
Could you point me in the right direction for this

Comment: Write another rule for stats, then. Each collection should have its own rules.  The documentation is helpful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started